# Errors with redirects Flask-socketio

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I wrote this code with flask socketio

to see learn the modual but when I leave the chat room and enter it again I get bombardment of get request from the room.
and get the redirected error on my browser

I was expecting to get to re-join the room with a diferent name once I left I dont know if I have to delete the session logs or what when I press leave.

```
            from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for
        from flask_socketio import join_room, leave_room, send, SocketIO

        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "FioraKing"
        socketio = SocketIO(app)

        # Usar codigo fixo para a sala
        fixed_room_code = "your_fixed_room_code"
        rooms = {fixed_room_code: {"members": 0, "messages": []}}

        # Update da rota para redirecionar para a sala
        @app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
        def home():
            if request.method == "POST":
                name = request.form.get("name")

                if not name:
                    return render_template("home.html", error="Porfavor Adiciona Nome.")

                session["room"] = fixed_room_code
                session["name"] = name
                return redirect(url_for("room"))

            # verificar se o nome e a sala estão na sessão
            if "name" in session and "room" in session:
                return redirect(url_for("room"))

            return render_template("home.html")

        @app.route("/room")
        def room():
            room = session.get("room")
            name = session.get("name")
            if room is None or name is None or room not in rooms:
                return redirect(url_for("home"))

            return render_template("room.html", code=room, messages=rooms[room]["messages"])

        @socketio.on("message")
        def message(data):
            room = session.get("room")
            if room not in rooms:
                return

            content = {
                "name": session.get("name"),
                "message": data["data"]
            }
            send(content, to=room)
            rooms[room]["messages"].append(content)
            print(f"{session.get('name')} said: {data['data']}")

        @socketio.on("connect")
        def connect():
            room = session.get("room")
            name = session.get("name")
            if not room or not name:
                return

            join_room(room)
            send({"name": name, "message": "entrou na sala"}, to=room)
            rooms[room]["members"] += 1
            print(f"{name} joined room {room}")

        # Update da rota para sair da sala
        @socketio.on("disconnect")
        def disconnect():
            room = session.get("room")
            name = session.get("name")
            if room in rooms:
                rooms[room]["members"] -= 1
                if rooms[room]["members"] <= 0:
                    del rooms[room]

            send({"name": name, "message": "saiu da sala"}, to=room)
            leave_room(room)
            print(f"{name} has left the room {room}")

            # apagar a sessão
            session.pop("room", None)
            session.pop("name", None)


        @app.route("/leave_session", methods=["POST"])
        def leave_session():
            session.clear()
            return redirect(url_for("home"))



        if __name__ == "__main__":
            socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```